# Sharepoint DateTimeControl

Tags: sharepoint-2010, datetimepicker

How to format date in Sharepoint DateTime Control?

Answer (score 2):

DateTimeControl.LocaleId = SPContext.Current.RegionalSettings.LocaleId 
Or put the LocaleId if it does not work, I encounter that sometimes 
i.e

DateTimeControl.LocaleId = 2057 for UK
DateTimeControl.LocaleId = 1031 for German

Answer (score 0):

set
DateTimeControl.LocaleId =  Convert.ToInt32(SPContext.Current.RegionalSettings.LocaleID)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom format property

dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
   dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy - dddd";

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: While the link might contain useful information, it's better to include the relevant part here. Links can become invalid.